# Is there other method to update data in custom listview in provider Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

I am fetching data from firebase and show in listview. I store data in list and and then notify it but still list length is null.
I study all related question but still not get solution.

i want whenever I add some new data in firebase It appears same time in listview. So for that I am using provider here. please also give me some idea for this.

Thank you in advance

Here is Code

```
      class Home121 extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        _Home121State createState() => _Home121State();
      }

      final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Data");

      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        Future<void> StoreData() async {
          dynamic key=CreateCryptoRandomString(32);
          fb.child(key).set({
            "id": key,
            "link": "EasyCoding",
          }).then((value) {
            ShowToastNow();
          });
        }
        return ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskManager>(
            create: (context) => TaskManager(),
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Kkkk"),
              ),
              body: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                    8,
                  ),
                  child: Consumer<TaskManager>(
                      builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                        return myModel.list.length==0? Text("zero"):ListView.builder(
                          itemCount:myModel.list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index){
                            return Text(
                              myModel.list[index].Name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      }

                  )
              ),
            )
        );

      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        TaskManager task=TaskManager();
        task.GetData();
      }
      }


      class TaskManager extends ChangeNotifier{

        List<Model> list=new List();
        GetData(){
          //get data here
        }

        AddNewTask(){
          // add data to databse
          list.add(model);
          notifyListeners();
        }
      }
```

Edit:

```
      class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskManager>(
              create: (context) => TaskManager(),
              child: Home121());
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in `initState()` you are creating another instance of `TaskManager` and calling the method `GetData()` on that instance.

So the instance of `TaskManager` which the `Consumer` widgets use is different and so the list inside that one always remain empty.

Instead you need to do this inside `initState()`..

```
void initState() {
    TaskManager task = Provider.of<TaskManager>(context);
    task.GetData();
}
```

By doing this, you call the `GetData()` method on the same instance which is used by the `Consumer` widgets.

Comment: Thanks Sir but Now Its give too many errors like Could not find the correct Provider<TaskManager> above this Home121 Widget. This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
I/flutter (14535): of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

Comment: For this you will need to remove the `ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskManager>` from inside the `build()` method and wrap  the `Home121()` widget with `ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskManager>` instead.

Comment: still giving error: dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _Home121State.initState() completed.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include how you did the last change in the code?

Comment: Not sure, but can you remove that and try by wrapping the `MaterialApp()` with `ChangeNotifierProvider<TaskManager>` instead ?

Comment: anyone need provider with dynamic listview.builder code then check my channel thanks  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8UsfNYmbKiRJvI9ZhhApEw?view_as=subscriber